# Google sign in error in Eclipse IDE: SIGN-IN REQUIRED

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am developing an android application where I am integrating the google drive in my app. I am developing this application using Eclipse IDE. Below is my code

```
private void saveFiletoDrive() {


    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveContentsResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult) {

            if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new Drive backup.");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error on loading Google Drive. Retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Backup to drive started.");

       try {    
            File dbFile = new File(inFileName);

            FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

            ZipOutputStream outStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(driveContentsResult.getDriveContents().getOutputStream()));

            outStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(inFileName));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            /*outStream.close();
            inStream.close();*/

        //drive file Metadata
            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setTitle("database_backup.db")
                    .setMimeType("application/db")
                    .build();

         // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                    .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                    .setInitialDriveContents(driveContentsResult.getDriveContents())
                    .build(mGoogleApiClient);

            startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();


        }

    });

}
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {

       mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
               .addApi(Drive.API)
               .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
               .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
               .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
               .build();
   }

   mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

}

```
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
            // Called after a file is saved to Drive.
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Backup successfully saved.");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Backup successufly loaded!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

        case REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                DriveId driveId = data.getParcelableExtra(
                        OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
                //Toast.makeText(this, driveId.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                DriveFile file = driveId.asDriveFile();
                importFromDrive(file);
            }
    }
}
```

the Logcat message I am getting is

```
Google Drive Activity(13699): GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{41f257d8: android.os.BinderProxy@41f25778}, message=null}
```

I added the permissions in manifest file and even enabled the Google Drive API.Anyone please let me know the solution for this

Comment: Can you please try and repeat your problem using a slightly smaller set of code rather than just dumping everything on here and expecting people to filter through it for you?

Comment: @LordWilmore yh okay.. But I think I removed almost all code and only the functionality is remaining,

Comment: Following the codes [quickstart from Drive Android documentation](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart), there is a part where "How can I run it?" it stated that you have to use [OAuth 2.0 client](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started). Follow the link for OAuth 2.0 credential to authorize your app's Drive API requests. Hope this helps.